# A ball (character) falls in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, rigid-bodies, collider

I have a ball (character) and you can control it and pick up weapons on the map. So, here are the settings of my ball:

[image]

The weapon also has a collider, and the platform on which the character walks has a Mesh Collider. There are also walls on the map. My problem lies in the walls, a character with a weapon taken, if he runs into a wall with them, the character begins to turn over and generally move as I do not need, even when the axes that I do not need are frozen in the Rigidbody.

Maybe the point is that two colliders meet each other? I don’t know, please tell me the solution to the problem.

Here is a video of how my character fails (if with a weapon) when colliding with another collider (Wall):
[Click](https://youtu.be/1pGixhM4EBg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help. You need to create a new layer for the walls, then go to the guns collider and in include layers choose everything except your newly created layer, then in exclude layers select only your newly created layer. If you want players not be able to shoot trough walls, add a collider to bullet.

Comment: And something else, if you want to prevant players to shoot trough walls for 100%, add a gameobject wich has a trigger collider and in gun script check if player is touching it, if yes, then shoot. If helped, please like my answer. Have a nice day